# Coldfusion call onServerStart manually

Tags: coldfusion

Is there a way to quickly call onServerStart in the Server.cfc component without actually restarting the service?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can call it by creating an instance of the server.cfc

```
objServer = createObject("component", "server");
objServer.onServerStart();
```

Ray has also written a great blog post on the subject: http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2011/6/14/Can-you-manually-run-your-ColdFusions-onServerStart-CFC

Comment: You mean the onServerStart stuff ? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WS7AC9408A-1AC6-4ab7-9C8E-CF1DA8FCA16D.html (The rest ie syntax obviously works for any component, including application.cfc)